# TTL Gates Power Dissipation Values

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, logic-gates, ttl, power-dissipation

I am not finding any datasheets that provide clear information about the **power dissipation** of some gates of the **74LS series**:

*08, 02, 04, 00, 32 and 86.*

Can someone help?

Comment: You might be looking for this https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ttl-data-book-vol1-010496/dp/3880780781/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=The+TTL+Data+Book&qid=1600082370&sr=8-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not finding any datasheets that provide clear information about the power dissipation

Because total power dissipation depends on the outputs.

For example, this is from 74LS08:

[image]

Total power dissipation is the product of supply current and supply voltage:
$$
P_T=I_{CC} \ V_{CC}
$$

Note that all the logic gate datasheets provide supply current information.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! So if I am asked to give the power dissipation (in a lab report), do you think I should just put it as a formula?

Comment: @RalphAouad The dissipation is defined with its formula. If the dissipation is really critical (e.g. for battery-powered systems) then you have to measure, If not then you can give it as a formula. Even a max. value could be sufficient.